# How to close the drop down list of JCombobox when we click on custom?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a JCombobox in which when I select any one from drop down list of JCombobox ,the selected item is opening but when I click on "Custom" among one of the drop down list I have to open a daiolg ,here daiolg is opening but drop down list is not closing I want to hide the drop down when I click on Custom. here is my sample code....

```
private PropertyChangeSupport   pcs;///here Iam using ActionListener and PopupMenuListener
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
if(ae.getSource() instanceof  ComboBox )
{
ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)ae.getSource();
Object selectedItem = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
if(selectedItem != null && (!selectedItem.equals("(Custom..)")))
{
pcs.firePropertyChange("ITEM_SELECTED",getCaption(),null);  
}}}
public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) 
{
ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)e.getSource();
Object repeatedSelectedItem = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
if(repeatedSelectedItem != null && repeatedSelectedItem.equals("(Custom..)"))
{
invokeCustomFilterDialog(repeatedSelectedItem, comboBox);
}}  
private void invokeCustomFilterDialog(Object repeatedSelectedItem, ComboBox comboBox)
{
customFilterDialog.showDialog();    //here Iam opening dailog...
if(customFilterDialog.isCustomFilterAppliedFlag() == true)
{                   
pcs.firePropertyChange("ITEM_SELECTED",getCaption(),null);
}
else
{comboBox.setSelectedItem(lastSelectedItem);}}
public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) 
{ }
public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) 
{
ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)e.getSource();
this.lastSelectedItem = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
}
```

Comment: To get help you need to provide a short runnable example ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org)). I cannot even compile the code, you've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.

For example

```
public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
        final JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
        final Object repeatedSelectedItem = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
        if (repeatedSelectedItem != null
                && repeatedSelectedItem.equals("(Custom..)")) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      invokeCustomFilterDialog(repeatedSelectedItem, comboBox);
                  }
            });

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

combobox.getUI().setPopupVisible(combobox, false);